# WPF Xaml updating listView to List<string> using INotifyPropertyChanged

Tags: wpf

I have a simple problem. I have a listView and it's datasource is a List. It is not updated immediately, but only when the codeflow ends.
What's the problem?

Below xaml:

```
<ListView x:Name="listView" ItemsSource="{Binding InfoBancaDatiAttuale}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="130" Margin="212,34,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="310">
        <ListView.View>
            <GridView>
                <GridViewColumn/>
            </GridView>
        </ListView.View>
    </ListView>
```

Below xaml.cs:

```
    private List<string> _infoBancaDatiAttuale;
    public List<string> InfoBancaDatiAttuale
    {
        get { return _infoBancaDatiAttuale; }
        set
        {
            _infoBancaDatiAttuale = value;
            onPropertyChanged("InfoBancaDatiAttuale");
        }
    }
    private void AddToListAndNotify(List<string> list, string value, string propertyNotify)
    {
        List<string> tempList = list;
        tempList.Add(value);
        InfoBancaDatiAttuale = tempList;
    }
```

In xaml.cs file I have also a procedure that perform instruction and should refresh UI. Percentage refresh a ProgressBar and I see that is update instantanely but InfoBancaDatiAttuale not refresh until the method finish.

```
public void performInstruction() {
    Percentage = (int)((1 * 100) / 11);
    AddToListAndNotify(InfoBancaDatiAttuale, "1) Eseguo login", "InfoBancaDatiAttuale");
    //...instruction
    Percentage = (int)((2 * 100) / 11);
    AddToListAndNotify(InfoBancaDatiAttuale, "2) Another operation", "InfoBancaDatiAttuale");
    //...instruction
    Percentage = (int)((3 * 100) / 11);
    AddToListAndNotify(InfoBancaDatiAttuale, "3) Another operation", "InfoBancaDatiAttuale");
}
```

What's the problem?

Comment: Try to use an `ObservableCollection<T>` for the `InfoBancaDatiAttuale`, this Type of collection notifies the UI automatically when Items are added, removed etc.

Comment: Can be problem INotifyPropertyChanged? I also implement interface INotifyCollectionChanged?

Answer (score 1):

Your issue is nothing to do with `INotifyPropertyChanged`, `INotifyCollectionChanged` and you dont need to use an `ObservableCollection` (although it would be slightly more efficient)

Your problem is that your `performInstruction` Method is running on the UI Thread and the Dispatcher is unable to update the user interface until the method has completed, which is why nothing happens until the method has completed.

What you could to is:

```
    public void performInstruction() {
        Task.Run(() => {
           Percentage = (int)((1 * 100) / 11);
           AddToListAndNotify(InfoBancaDatiAttuale, "1) Eseguo login", 
   "InfoBancaDatiAttuale");
           //...instruction
           Percentage = (int)((2 * 100) / 11);
           AddToListAndNotify(InfoBancaDatiAttuale, "2) Another operation", 
   "InfoBancaDatiAttuale");
           //...instruction
           Percentage = (int)((3 * 100) / 11);
           AddToListAndNotify(InfoBancaDatiAttuale, "3) Another operation", 
   "InfoBancaDatiAttuale");
       };
    }
```

And before anyone suggests that you need to marshal the property changes up to the dispatcher thread, I can assure you that it isnt necessary.

Comment: I'm curious why you don't need to explicitly make the property changes on the dispatcher thread.

Comment: Because you just dont, the WPF rendering system does it for you. Only DependencyProperties need to be marshalled. Its a common misconception by people obsessed with MVVM frameworks

Answer (score 0):

You should use `ObservableCollection<string>`. It will fire the `CollectionChanged` event of the `INotifyCollectionChanged` interface whenever an item is added to or removed from the collection.

```
private ObservableCollection<string> _items;
public ObservableCollection<string> Items => _items ?? (_items = new ObservableCollection<string>());
```